# Return multiple values in an array from an array of objects

Tags: php

A function I run returns the below:

```
Array ( [0] => WC_Memberships_User_Membership Object ( [id] => 148489 [plan_id] => 148071 [plan] => WC_Memberships_Membership_Plan Object ( [id] => 148071 [name] => Groups **[slug] => groups** [post] => WP_Post Object ( [ID] => 148071 [post_author] => 1 [post_date] => 2017-05-12 11:15:21 [post_date_gmt] => 2017-05-12 10:15:21 [post_content] => [post_title] => Groups [post_excerpt] => [post_status] => publish [comment_status] => closed [ping_status] => closed [post_password] => [post_name] => groups [to_ping] => [pinged] => [post_modified] => 2017-05-12 11:48:07 [post_modified_gmt] => 2017-05-12 10:48:07 [post_content_filtered] => [post_parent] => 0 [guid] => http://dev3.benefacto.org/?post_type=wc_membership_plan&p=148071 [menu_order] => 0 [post_type] => wc_membership_plan [post_mime_type] => [comment_count] => 0 [filter] => raw ) [access_method_meta:protected] => _access_method [default_access_method:protected] => unlimited [access_length_meta:protected] => _access_length [access_start_date_meta:protected] => _access_start_date [access_end_date_meta:protected] => _access_end_date [product_ids_meta:protected] => _product_ids [members_area_meta:protected] => _members_area_sections [email_content_meta:protected] => _email_content [rules:WC_Memberships_Membership_Plan:private] => Array ( ) ) [user_id] => 12312800 [status] => wcm-active [post] => WP_Post Object ( [ID] => 148489 [post_author] => 12312800 [post_date] => 2017-05-28 00:04:02 [post_date_gmt] => 2017-05-27 23:04:02 [post_content] => [post_title] => Auto Draft [post_excerpt] => [post_status] => wcm-active [comment_status] => closed [ping_status] => closed [post_password] => um_592a05dbb3501 [post_name] => auto-draft-2 [to_ping] => [pinged] => [post_modified] => 2017-05-28 00:04:02 [post_modified_gmt] => 2017-05-27 23:04:02 [post_content_filtered] => [post_parent] => 148071 [guid] => http://dev3.benefacto.org/?post_type=wc_user_membership&p=148489 [menu_order] => 0 [post_type] => wc_user_membership [post_mime_type] => [comment_count] => 0 [filter] => raw ) [product:WC_Memberships_User_Membership:private] => [type:protected] => manually-assigned [start_date_meta:protected] => _start_date [end_date_meta:protected] => _end_date [cancelled_date_meta:protected] => _cancelled_date [paused_date_meta:protected] => _paused_date [paused_intervals_meta:protected] => _paused_intervals [product_id_meta:protected] => _product_id [order_id_meta:protected] => _order_id [previous_owners_meta:protected] => _previous_owners ) [1] => WC_Memberships_User_Membership Object ( [id] => 148483 [plan_id] => 148169 [plan] => WC_Memberships_Membership_Plan Object ( [id] => 148169 [name] => London **[slug] => london** [post] => WP_Post Object ( [ID] => 148169 [post_author] => 1 [post_date] => 2017-05-14 11:12:52 [post_date_gmt] => 2017-05-14 10:12:52 [post_content] => [post_title] => London [post_excerpt] => [post_status] => publish [comment_status] => closed [ping_status] => closed [post_password] => [post_name] => london [to_ping] => [pinged] => [post_modified] => 2017-05-15 18:17:18 [post_modified_gmt] => 2017-05-15 17:17:18 [post_content_filtered] => [post_parent] => 0 [guid] => http://dev3.benefacto.org/?post_type=wc_membership_plan&p=148169 [menu_order] => 0 [post_type] => wc_membership_plan [post_mime_type] => [comment_count] => 0 [filter] => raw ) [access_method_meta:protected] => _access_method [default_access_method:protected] => unlimited [access_length_meta:protected] => _access_length [access_start_date_meta:protected] => _access_start_date [access_end_date_meta:protected] => _access_end_date [product_ids_meta:protected] => _product_ids [members_area_meta:protected] => _members_area_sections [email_content_meta:protected] => _email_content [rules:WC_Memberships_Membership_Plan:private] => Array ( ) ) [user_id] => 12312800 [status] => wcm-active [post] => WP_Post Object ( [ID] => 148483 [post_author] => 12312800 [post_date] => 2017-05-24 15:34:16 [post_date_gmt] => 2017-05-24 14:34:16 [post_content] => [post_title] => [post_excerpt] => [post_status] => wcm-active [comment_status] => open [ping_status] => closed [post_password] => um_592599e82db15 [post_name] => 148483 [to_ping] => [pinged] => [post_modified] => 2017-05-24 15:34:16 [post_modified_gmt] => 2017-05-24 14:34:16 [post_content_filtered] => [post_parent] => 148169 [guid] => http://dev3.benefacto.org/?post_type=wc_user_membership&p=148483 [menu_order] => 0 [post_type] => wc_user_membership [post_mime_type] => [comment_count] => 0 [filter] => raw ) [product:WC_Memberships_User_Membership:private] => [type:protected] => manually-assigned [start_date_meta:protected] => _start_date [end_date_meta:protected] => _end_date [cancelled_date_meta:protected] => _cancelled_date [paused_date_meta:protected] => _paused_date [paused_intervals_meta:protected] => _paused_intervals [product_id_meta:protected] => _product_id [order_id_meta:protected] => _order_id [previous_owners_meta:protected] => _previous_owners ) )
```

I want to pull out the slug names into a simpler array equivalent to this:

```
$slugnames = array(groups,london)
```

I can get an individual slug name using the following:

```
echo $memberships[0]->plan->slug;
```

But I want all of them in array.

I know I have to do something using 'foreach' but not sure what!

Any suggestions much appreciated.

Comment: Great. Thanks Constatin. I used this code to print the output.

`foreach ( $memberships as $membership) {
    
    print_r($membership->plan->slug);
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code. Should solve your problem.

```
$slugs = [];
foreach ($memberships as $item) {
    $slugs[] = $item->plan->slug;
}
print_r($slugs); // view result
```

Comment: Thank you Thomas. Works just as required.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to looping You can use [`array_map`](http://php.net/array_map):

```
$slugs = array_map(function($membership){
   return $membership->plan->slug;
   }, $memberships);
```

Comment: Works well. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You also can use array_walk(),

```
$slugs = [];
array_walk($memberships, function($v, $k) use($slugs) {
  $slugs[] = $v->plan->slug;
});
```