# Get results from array by not using the key

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I have the following code to get an array of looped posts that the user has a status of 'active'.

In that array I have multiple entries for "slug" like this.

```
["slug"]=>string(9) "the_bbc""
```

I can't pull in the data based on string number - "string(9)" as they're all different.

How can I echo "the_bbc" by searching for ["slug"] and return all results.

```
<?php $user_id = get_current_user_id();
$active_memberships = wc_memberships_get_user_memberships( $user_id, 'active' ); // userID and active user ?>

<pre><?php  var_dump ($active_memberships, $product_id); ?></pre>
```

Yes this looks quite novice and have been told yesterday by another person but I'm in my first year in college studying php.

Thanks

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please provide example data for `$active_memberships` and what output you expect for that sample.

Comment: Can you show what returning `print_r($active_membership);` ?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "string number", and the `string(9)` is the type of the value, it has nothing to do with accessing that value, and you don't need to know that value before hand.

Comment: isn't `wc_memberships_get_user_memberships()` a WooCommerce function? shouldn't this post be tagged accordingly?

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44222408/return-multiple-values-in-an-array-from-an-array-of-objects the accepted answer looks exactly like what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple "slug" in an array you can loop through it with a foreach(), ex:

```
foreach ( $active_memberships['slug'] as $slug) {
   //do whatever with this variable
}
```

I hope that I understood you correctly. Please provide a better description next time.